# I keep getting this problem in my programming

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Transactions will be taken from a holding
table (NEW_TRANSACTIONS) and inserted into the TRANSACTION_DETAIL and
TRANSACTION_HISTORY tables. 
the appropriate account balance will be
updated in the ACCOUNT table.

My code keep getting this problem: "exact fetch returns more than requested number of row"
[the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6s4L9.png)

**Error report -
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at line 28
01422. 00000 -  "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"
*Cause:    The number specified in exact fetch is less than the rows returned.
*Action:   Rewrite the query or change number of rows requested**

DECLARE

```
r_new_trans NEW_TRANSACTIONS%ROWTYPE;
cursor c_trans_data IS
SELECT UNIQUE transaction_no, transaction_date,description, account_no, transaction_type, transaction_amount
FROM new_transactions;

TYPE UP_ACCOUNT IS RECORD (
      A_NO ACCOUNT.ACCOUNT_NO%type,
      A_TYPE_CODE account.account_type_code%type,
      A_BALANCE account.account_balance%TYPE,
      A_trans_type account_type.default_trans_type%type);

update_a UP_ACCOUNT;

--v_new_trans_amount TRANSACTION_DETAIL.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT%TYPE := 0;
v_new_balance ACCOUNT.ACCOUNT_BALANCE%TYPE := 0; 
v_transaction_debit NEW_TRANSACTIONS.TRANSACTION_TYPE%TYPE := 'D';
v_transaction_credit  NEW_TRANSACTIONS.TRANSACTION_TYPE%TYPE := 'C';
v_transaction_number  new_transactions.transaction_no%TYPE;

v_transaction_variable new_transactions.transaction_no%TYPE := 0;
v_transaction_deta_variable new_transactions.transaction_no%TYPE := 0;  

v_temp_balance account.account_balance%type := 0;
```

BEGIN

```
SELECT account_no, a.account_type_code, account_balance, default_trans_type into update_a
FROM ACCOUNT a JOIN ACCOUNT_TYPE at on a.account_type_code = at.account_type_code ;

--/1st cursor/
FOR r_trans IN c_trans_data LOOP
        IF(r_trans.TRANSACTION_NO <> v_transaction_variable)
        THEN 
            INSERT INTO TRANSACTION_HISTORY
            VALUES (r_trans.TRANSACTION_NO, r_trans.TRANSACTION_DATE,r_trans.DESCRIPTION);         
        END IF;
        v_transaction_variable := r_trans.TRANSACTION_NO;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_transaction_variable');

        IF(r_trans.TRANSACTION_NO <> v_transaction_variable)
        THEN 
            INSERT INTO TRANSACTION_DETAIL
            VALUES (r_trans.ACCOUNT_NO, r_trans.TRANSACTION_NO,r_trans.TRANSACTION_TYPE,r_trans.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT);         
        END IF;
        v_transaction_deta_variable:= r_trans.TRANSACTION_NO;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_transaction_deta_variable');

        IF r_trans.transaction_type <>  update_a.A_trans_type
            THEN 
            v_temp_balance := v_temp_balance - r_trans.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT;

            UPDATE account 
            SET account_balance = v_temp_balance
            WHERE account_no = r_trans.account_no;

        ELSIF r_trans.transaction_type = update_a.A_trans_type
            THEN 
            v_temp_balance := v_temp_balance + r_trans.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT;

            UPDATE account 
            SET account_balance = v_temp_balance
            WHERE account_no = r_trans.account_no;

        END IF; 
END LOOP;
```

END;

Transactions will be taken from a holding
table (NEW_TRANSACTIONS) and inserted into the TRANSACTION_DETAIL and
TRANSACTION_HISTORY tables. 
the appropriate account balance will be
updated in the ACCOUNT table.

Comment: so, is the programming language is which? oracle, c# (where?) or *javascript* (where?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing problem in `SELECT .. INTO` statement as it is returning more than 1 records and you are storing it in a `UDT` type of variable which is made to hold only 1 record.

You need to declare it something like following:

```
Type UP_ACCOUNT_TBL IS TABLE OF UP_ACCOUNT index by PLS_INTEGER;
update_a UP_ACCOUNT_TBL;
```

And your select query should look like this:

```
SELECT UP_ACCOUNT(account_no, a.account_type_code, account_balance, default_trans_type) into update_a
FROM ACCOUNT a JOIN ACCOUNT_TYPE at on a.account_type_code = at.account_type_code ;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: If this answer solved your question then please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, so that your question is marked as resolved.